# How to resolve issue: Cannot resolve symbol 'CreateTodoInput'?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have synced and resynced the gradle files and built and rebuilt the app many times. I've closed android studio and even restarted the computer. Same error appears.

I've been following the aws tutorial and I'm on step five in the paragraph:

```
public void runMutation(){
    CreateTodoInput createTodoInput = CreateTodoInput.builder().
        name("Use AppSync").
        description("Realtime and Offline").
        build();

    mAWSAppSyncClient.mutate(CreateTodoMutation.builder().input(createTodoInput).build())
        .enqueue(mutationCallback);
}

private GraphQLCall.Callback<CreateTodoMutation.Data> mutationCallback = new GraphQLCall.Callback<CreateTodoMutation.Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<CreateTodoMutation.Data> response) {
        Log.i("Results", "Added Todo");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    }
};
```

There is a red underline beneath CreateTodoInput, mutationCallback as well as several others.

Comment: Where is CreateTodoInput defined, and are you sure it is linked in to your project? You don't post the source of the aws tutorial you're using, so it is unlikely anyone will be able to guess at that step five is, much less the preceding steps.

Comment: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start

Comment: You're making people do a lot of guesswork. Where do you expect CreateTodoInput to be defined? As written, your question is not helping others understand what might be wrong, but typically when you see an resolved symbol that is defined outside of your code, it is because the defining library is not linked in or imported. Without the full source of your class and at least your build.gradle files, it's impossible to speculate which it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you should have GraphQL endpoint and API key after step 4.

Make sure you add `classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:2.9.+'` to `project/build.gradle` and
add the below dependencies in `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'

dependencies {
   //Base SDK
   implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.15.+'
   //AppSync SDK
   implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.8.+'
   implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
   implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
}
```

After step 4 (amplify push), make sure to `BUILD` your android project and `SYNC` all the gradle files

Here is the [AWS  Amplify tutorial page](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start?ref=amplify-android-btn)